# Org Babel failing with Recursive Functions

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I’ve done quite a lot of source level blocks in org-mode, but I think I have a failure scenario if called functions inside the source code blocks are recursive.

The `ifconfig` program displays all the important information, just in the wrong format. Let’s fix that. First, let’s retrieve the results and we’ll store that in a name, `ifconfig_data`:

```
#+NAME: ifconfig_data
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer
  ifconfig -a
#+END_SRC
```

Which spills out:

```
#+RESULTS: ifconfig_data
:RESULTS:
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 6c:40:08:b7:ce:b8
        inet6 fe80::6e40:8ff:feb7:ceb8%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
        inet 192.168.77.40 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 192.168.77.255
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
...
```

We can access that data easily in standard org-mode Babel thingie:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var datastring=ifconfig_data :results value
  (format "Results: %s" datastring)
#+END_SRC
```

However, the output format is awful, and I would like to have a list of tuples, where each tuple has the interface and the IP address.  Since some interfaces may not have an IPv4 address (which is what I’m wanting).

To address this, I have a recursive function that calls itself for each regular expression match:

```
1. Matched the Interface
   2. The name of the Interface
3. Matches the Address
   4. Optional `addr:` section that we don’t care about
   5. The value of the address
```

If the match is on an address, we assume that we passed in the interface name as a `header` parameter, so that we can /build up/ the result.

```
#+NAME: ifconfig-display
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var datastring=ifconfig_data :results value
  (defun split-ifconfig (datastr pos header)
    "Assumes that the DATASTR is a string datastrput from ifconfig.  The POS is position within the string to search.  The HEADER is the current interface address."
    (when (string-match "\\(^\\([^ :]+\\):?\\ \\)\\|\\( *inet \\(addr:\\)?\\([0-9.]+\\)\\)" datastr pos)
      (cond
       ;; Interface:: Recurse with the name of this new header
       ((match-string 1 datastr)
            (split-ifconfig datastr (match-end 0) (match-string 2 datastr)))

       ;; Address:: Return a list with our interface header, the
       ;;           address, and the results of parsing the rest
       ((match-string 3 datastr)
            (cons (list header (match-string 5 datastr))
                    (split-ifconfig datastr (match-end 0) nil))))))

  (split-ifconfig datastring 0 nil)
#+END_SRC
```

This works if I evaluate the function stuff directly with `C-x C-e`.

The last line, however, in the code block returns `nil`. Always. The `datastring` contains the data. The function, `split-ifconfig` that was defined in the function is called. Still no go.

This doesn’t work, even if I pre-load the function into the global function space, and call it from the block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var out=ifconfig_data :results value
  (split-ifconfig out 0 nil)
#+END_SRC
```

I’ve tried making the `datastr` aspect a global variable, and not keep passing it. Still no go.

Comment: Are you the author of [Literate DevOps](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-devops.html)?

Comment: Sorry, but I just noticed this question. Yes, that is my blog.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem was with the regular expression matching the preceding end-line character before the protocol name.  Below is your version with that problem fixed, plus a non-recursive version, in case you suspect it has anything to do with recursion.

```
#+NAME: ifconfig_data
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer
  ifconfig -a
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: ifconfig-display
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var datastring=ifconfig_data :results value
  (defun split-ifconfig (datastr pos header)
    "Assumes that the DATASTR is a string datastrput from ifconfig.  
      The POS is position within the string to search.  
      The HEADER is the current interface address."
    (when (string-match "\\(^\\([^ :]+\\):?\\ \\)\\|\\( *inet \\(addr:\\)?\\([0-9.]+\\)\\)"
                        datastr pos)
      (cond
       ;; Interface:: Recurse with the name of this new header
       ((match-string 1 datastr)
        (split-ifconfig datastr (match-end 0) (match-string 2 datastr)))

       ;; Address:: Return a list with our interface header, the
       ;;           address, and the results of parsing the rest
       ((match-string 3 datastr)
        (cons (list (org-trim header) (match-string 5 datastr))
              (split-ifconfig datastr (match-end 0) nil))))))

  (split-ifconfig datastring 0 nil)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: ifconfig-display
| lo   |     127.0.0.1 |
| ppp0 | xx.xxx.xxx.xx |

#+NAME: ifconfig-display-2
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var datastring=ifconfig_data :results value
  (defun split-ifconfig (datastr pos header)
    "Assumes that the DATASTR is a string datastrput from ifconfig.  
          The POS is position within the string to search.  
          The HEADER is the current interface address."
    (cl-loop with state = :after
             and interface = nil
             and address = nil
             and result = nil
             for line in (split-string datastr "\n" nil "[\t ]+") do
             (cond
              ((string-equal line "")
               (when address
                 (push `(,interface ,address) result))
               (setf state :after interface nil address nil))
              ((eql state :after)
               (setf interface (cl-first (split-string line "[:\t ]"))
                     state :inside))
              ((string-prefix-p "inet " line)
               (setf address (cl-second (split-string line)))))
             finally (cl-return (nreverse result))))

  (split-ifconfig datastring 0 nil)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: ifconfig-display-2
| lo   |     127.0.0.1 |
| ppp0 | xx.xxx.xxx.xx |
```

PS, you could have tested the function by doing something like (in `*scratch*` or REPL:

```
(let ((datastring (shell-command-to-string "ifconfig -a")))
  (split-ifconfig datastring 0 nil))
```

You'd see right away where the problem is.